# Android: Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I have an application with one activity and this activity has a fragment. In this fragment I show in a Listview "pending orders". I set up I method to reload the search in my database for the pending order once every 55 seconds. And I reload the Activity once every 60 seconds. The problem is that something when the fragment is being loaded I get this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getCacheDir()' on a null object reference

And I am trying to track this problem but it's not very easy because I am still a beginner in Android development.

This is the fragment:

```
public class PendingOrdersFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    ListView lstOrders;
    ArrayList<ChefOrderList> orderLists;
    TextView empty;

    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, null);

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        doTheAutoRefresh();
        lstOrders = (ListView) view.findViewById(lstFood);
        lstOrders.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        empty = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.empty);

        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorPrimary);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                if (NetworkHelper.isOnline(getActivity())) {
                    callServiceForMenuStatusDetails(PrefernceHelper.getString(getActivity(),Commons.Constants.DATE));
                } else {
                    NetworkHelper.noNetworkToast(getActivity());
                }
            }
        });

        System.out.println(PrefernceHelper.getString(getActivity(), Commons.Constants.DATE));

        if (NetworkHelper.isOnline(getActivity())) {
            callServiceForMenuStatusDetails(PrefernceHelper.getString(getActivity(), Commons.Constants.DATE));
        } else {
            NetworkHelper.noNetworkToast(getActivity());
        }

    }

    //ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    private void callServiceForMenuStatusDetails(String date) {

        //progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        //progressDialog.setTitle("Loading");
        //progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait");
        //progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        //progressDialog.show();

        new VolleyHelper(getActivity()).get("chefOrderDetailsByDate/" + PrefernceHelper.getString(getActivity(), Commons.Constants.USER_ID) + "/" + date, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                orderLists = new ArrayList<ChefOrderList>();
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("orderlist");
                    int pending = 0, accepted = 0, rejected = 0;

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        ChefOrderList orderList = new ChefOrderList();
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);


                        orderList.setOrderId(jsonObject.getString("orderid"));
                        orderList.setOrderStatus(jsonObject.getString("order_status"));
                        orderList.setOrderDate(jsonObject.getString("order_date"));
                        orderList.setOrderFrom(jsonObject.getString("orderfrom"));

                        if(jsonObject.getString("order_status").equals("Pending")) {
                            //System.out.println(orderList.getOrderId());
                            orderLists.add(orderList);
                            pending = pending + 1;
                            TabLayoutScreenActivity.orderSizeVariable = TabLayoutScreenActivity.orderSizeVariable + 1;
                        } else if (jsonObject.getString("order_status").equals("Order accepted by chef")){
                            accepted = accepted + 1;

                        } else if (jsonObject.getString("order_status").equals("Order rejected by chef")){
                            rejected = rejected + 1;
                        }
                    }

                    //for (int i= 0; i< orderLists.size();i++) {
                    //    System.out.println(orderLists.get(i).getOrderId());
                    //}

                    System.out.println("Variable: " + TabLayoutScreenActivity.orderSizeVariable);
                    System.out.println("Fixed: " + TabLayoutScreenActivity.orderSizeFixed);

                    if (TabLayoutScreenActivity.orderSizeVariable > TabLayoutScreenActivity.orderSizeFixed){
                        TabLayoutScreenActivity.orderSizeFixed = TabLayoutScreenActivity.orderSizeVariable;
                        PushNotification();
                    }
                    TabLayoutScreenActivity.orderSizeVariable = 0;



                    if(jsonArray.length() > 0 && pending!=0) {
                        lstOrders.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        empty.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        ChefOrderListAdapter adpater = new ChefOrderListAdapter(getActivity(), orderLists);
                        lstOrders.setAdapter(adpater);
                    }else {
                        lstOrders.setEmptyView(getView().findViewById(android.R.id.empty));
                        empty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        lstOrders.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }

                    //progressDialog.dismiss();


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void PushNotification()
    {
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getContext());
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getContext(), TabLayoutScreenActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getContext(),0,notificationIntent,0);

        //set
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.chef_hat);
        builder.setContentText("Click here to open the app.");
        builder.setContentTitle("You have a new order!");
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=21) {
            builder.setColor(Color.parseColor("#D8540D"));
        }
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);

        Notification notification = builder.build();
        nm.notify((int)System.currentTimeMillis(),notification);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        System.out.println("Test");
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("orderID", orderLists.get(position).getOrderId());
        intent.putExtra("orderFrom", orderLists.get(position).getOrderFrom());
        intent.setClass(getActivity(), OrderDetailsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        getActivity().finish();

    }

    private void doTheAutoRefresh() {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Auto refresh: Pending");
                //if (!(PrefernceHelper.getString(getActivity(), Commons.Constants.DATE).equals(null))) {
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                callServiceForMenuStatusDetails(postFormater.format(c.getTime()));
                //}
                doTheAutoRefresh();
            }
        }, 55000);
    }
}
```

This is the full log cat for the error:

[image]

Volley.java 43 is:

[image]

Volley.java 78 is:

[image]

VolleyHelper.java 34 is:

[image]

For the Pending order fragment:
Line 47 is:

```
public class PendingOrdersFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
```

Line 105 is:

```
new VolleyHelper(getActivity()).get("chefOrderDetailsByDate/" + PrefernceHelper.getString(getActivity(), Commons.Constants.USER_ID) + "/" + date, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
```

Line 222 is:

```
callServiceForMenuStatusDetails(postFormater.format(c.getTime()));
```

Comment: please post the code instead of screen

Comment: Hint: When the refresh timer fires, your fragment is no longer attached to an activity and `getActivity()` returns null.

Comment: laalto, the "doTheAutoRefresh()" in the fragment only re-calls the method that search in my database for the pending orders.

Comment: Yeah this logic should not be done in the fragment... This should be done in a service or at the least the activity.

Comment: So I should reload the Fragment in the Activity even though I am only calling the method to search in my database?

Comment: Check from where the null comes, postdelayed or onCreateView?

Comment: As you can read in the comments you are doing the refresh of the data somehow before the activity is recreated. That leads to the nullpointer you see. You can try to synchronize the runnables in such way that one the one for the activity starts the other one gets paused or destroyed and so on.

Answer (score 8):

Your Error means that the variable that the function *getCacheDir ()* uses is null. In this case your variable context. You can get your Application Context like this:

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the crash was happening because of activity reference, when I was trying to finish Activity, to restart the App.
The following error was coming for me:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.Activity.finish()' on a null object reference
```

I solved it like this, `NameOfActivity.this.finish()`.

Answer (score 0):

This Error is because the mContext which you are passing is null

```
//Put an if condition to check if mContext is null or not

     if(mContext()!=null) {
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext());               
        }
```